# How to burn an existing recovery partition to iso?

Tags: partitioning, iso

I'm using a laptop with a factory recovery partition. I'd like to scrap it, but I don't know if I might need it, so I'd prefer to create an ISO(s) from the partition if there's a good technique/method. Advice is appreciated.

(I should also mention that it needs to be a bootable iso.  I'm currently experimenting with using clonezilla to create images, and mkisofs to turn them into an ISO. Not sure yet if that will get the job done or if there's a better way.)

Comment: I've never considered this, but it sounds like a great idea! I'd love to have a backup of that recovery partition. (I note that in someways this is not Ubuntu specific, especially since such a recovery partition usually reloads Windows. Having said that obviously the questioner wants to know how to do this on Ubuntu, so it is definitely on topic.)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned - if you feel this is in error, then please ask a new question, or flag this explaining why and the moderators will reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd `dd` the partition contents to a file, zip it and burn to CD/DVD.

To copy contents of a partition to a file named recovery_partition.img in your home directory, use the following command:

> dd if=/dev/sdaX of=~/recovery_partition.img

where `/dev/sdaX` should be replaced by the name of the partition you'd like to back up.

To find out the name of the partition, use Disk Utility (System > Administration > Disk Utility).

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have Windows on your laptop? It usually will have an app on Windows that will do this for you :)

Comment: I'm not the original question asker, but I'm quite sure mine doesn't have such an app.

Comment: Hmm... I thought most computer manufactures had it...

Comment: @russjr08 Not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Note that at least as of Ubuntu 16 LTS, you can do the partition imaging from the disk utility (search for "disk" in the Dasboard).